# Drupal6: Mass Image Upload?

Tags: image, upload, drupal-6

I have a solid image gallery going, using CCK, Views, and Imagecache. However, this currently requires users to upload images one at a time, which is unacceptably tedious for most people. What is the best way to implement mass image upload on Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the development version of [the SWFUpload project](http://drupal.org/project/swfupload). There's also a [Java applet uploader](http://drupal.org/project/imagex) that may suit you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [image_fupload](http://drupal.org/project/image_fupload) might be what you're looking for.  Unfortunately, the D6 release is still just a RC.